# Why is only the innermost of these nested while loops working?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm newbie in Python.
I have this simple code

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

while a <= 5:
    while b <=3:
        while c <= 8:
            print a , b , c
            c += 1
        b += 1
    a += 1
```

And work only while with C

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 0 3
0 0 4
0 0 5
0 0 6
0 0 7
0 0 8
```

Why? How to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: This is not how you supposed to write loops in python. Use `for a in range(6)`.

Comment: @Ignacio Not sure that title makes any sense?

Comment: @agf: It only works the first time. After that, nothing.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's the answer. The question was why only the 'c' loop was working (or appearing to work) -- the innermost loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## First way

Your way will work, but you have to remember to reset the loop counters on each iteration.

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

while a <= 5:
    while b <=3:
        while c <= 8:
            print a , b , c
            c += 1
        b += 1
        c = 0 # reset
    a += 1
    b = 0 # reset
    c = 0 # reset
```

## Second way (Pythonic)

The first way involves a lot of bookkeeping. In Python, the easier way to specify a loop over a range of numbers is to use a `for` loop over an `xrange`* iterator:

```
for a in xrange(5+1): # Note xrange(n) produces 0,1,2...(n-1) and does not include n.
    for b in xrange (3+1):
        for c in xrange (8+1):
            print a,b,c
```

- Note: In Python 3, `xrange` is now called `range`. (Or more precisely, Python 3 `range` replaces Python 2.x's `range` and `xrange`.)

## Third way (best)

The second way can be simplified by application of `itertools.product()`, which takes in a number of iterables (lists) and returns every possible combination of each element from each list.

```
import itertools
for a,b,c in itertools.product(xrange(5+1),xrange(3+1),xrange(8+1)):
    print a,b,c
```

For these tricks and more, read [Dan Goodger's "Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html).

Comment: It's worth noting that ``xrange()`` is a builtin pre-Python 3.x, after that, just use ``range()``. Although, due to the ``print`` syntax used, it's clear the OP is using Python 2.x, it's still a good idea to mention for others.

Comment: @Lattyware: True. I will let your comment serve as the notice to Py3k users. ;)

Comment: I'd also argue that resetting the variables should happen before each ``while`` loop, to avoid doing it once at the start and then again after the end of each loop - not a big deal, but I think it reads better and it means less code. Obviously, that said, the latter solution(s) are the best option.

Comment: Note that their conditions are `<=` so you actually need `range(6)`, not (5).

Comment: It's always the nitpicking with you people, isn't it?! :) (Edited as noted.)

Comment: No need to reset `c` twice (in your first solution).

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to reset `b` and `c` at the top of the loops for `a` and `b` respectively. This is why we use `for` loops instead.

Answer (score 2):

whe while `c <= 8` gets looped while `c <= 8` so `c` gets to `8` and therefore  the program never has to execute that loop again.

Try setting `c = 0` at the end of the loop, as well as setting `b` and `a` to 0 after their loops or better yet make use of itertools or for loops.

Answer (score 0):

After the first while loop c will equal 9.  You never reset c so, `c <= 8` will never be true on the a or b loops.

If you reset each of them before their loops, it will work correctly.

```
a = 0
while a <= 5:
    b = 0
    while b <=3:
        c = 0
        while c <= 8:
            print a , b , c
            c += 1
        b += 1
    a += 1
```